# Given a Huffman tree, how to compute Huffman code for each symbol?

Tags: math, clojure, lisp

As the title stated, I'm writing a function to compute Huffman codes for symbols in a tree, but I feel completely lost.

A branch looks like this:

```
{:kind :branch, :frequency frequency, :left child0, :right child1}
```

A leaf looks like this:

```
{:kind :leaf, :frequency frequency, :value symbol}
```

And the code itself is structured like this:

```
{:tree tree, :length length, :bits bits}
```

I have the main function already (looks like this):

```
 (defn huffman-codes
    "Given a Huffman tree, compute the Huffman codes for each symbol in it. 
    Returns a map mapping each symbol to a sequence of bits (0 or 1)." 
   [T]

   (into {} (for [s (all-symbols T)] [s (find-in-tree s T '())])

 ) 
 )
```

`all-symbols` return the set of all symbols in the tree and I am to write a helper function `find-in-tree` that finds the bit string of a symbol

**EDIT:**
I've tried this now and it gets me closer to what I want, but still not right (see error message below)

```clj
    (defn find-in-tree 
       [s T l]
    
       (if (isleaf? T)
           {(:value T) l}
           (merge (find-in-tree s (:left T) (concat l '(0)))
              (find-in-tree s (:right T) (concat l '(1)))
        )
       )
    
    )
```

`ERROR -- got' {:c {:d (0 0 0), :c (0 0 1), :b (0 1), :a (1)}, :b {:d (0 0 0), :c (0 0 1), :b (0 1), :a (1)}, :d {:d (0 0 0), :c (0 0 1), :b (0 1), :a (1)}, :a {:d (0 0 0), :c (0 0 1), :b (0 1), :a (1)}} ', expected ' {:d (0 0 0), :c (0 0 1), :b (0 1), :a (1)} '`

It gets all the correct bit strings but assigns the whole map to every value, and I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Huffman tree is valid (meaning we can ignore `:frequency`), and that `0` means 'left' and `1` means 'right':

```clj
(defn code-map
  "Given a Huffman tree, returns a map expressing each symbol's code"
  [{:keys [kind left right value]} code]
  (if (= kind :leaf)
    {value code}
    (merge (code-map left (str code "0"))
           (code-map right (str code "1")))))
```

Demo:

```clj
;; sample tree
(def root 
  {:kind :branch 
   :left {:kind :branch
          :left {:kind :leaf
                 :value "X"}
          :right {:kind :leaf
                  :value "Y"}}
   :right {:kind :leaf :value "Z"}})

;; make sure to pass it "" as second arg
(code-map root "")
;;=> {"X" "00", "Y" "01", "Z" "1"}
```

To clean this up, you could move the `""` arg into an inner helper function, and the recursion could be made TCO-able.

Comment: I drew some inspiration from your answer but my solution doesn't get me all the way to what I want. Could you see what's wrong?